# Less tedious way to generate poetry dependencies?

Tags: python-3.x, dependencies, static-analysis, python-poetry

Every time I start a new poetry project, I have to go through a tedious process of listing dependencies. These include:

- `poetry add` every dependency one by one even though it's already listed in my import block
- Source diving to figure out the actual minimum version of the package given the minimal functionality I use
- Going down the rabbit hole of CPython code to figure out the minimum version of Python

I don't really like the Poetry approach of just requiring whatever version I have installed. As a developer, I tend to install bleeding edge version of packages and Python, which many of my users don't have. I then get annoying bug reports that come down to "the python version is wrong" but the user is often very confused by the error messages. The process of finding minimum dependency versions is typically not very complicated, it's just tedious and not scalable.

Surely there is a tool out there that can do some static analysis and get me started with a basic dependency list? I understand that a perfect solution would likely be a lot of work, but a partial solution would be good enough for me. So long as it takes care of the bulk of the tedious work, I don't mind dealing with the handful of remaining corner cases by hand.

PyCharm seems able to at least compare the package names in `requirements.txt` to my imports. Unfortunately this doesn't work for the poetry dependencies, not even with the Poetry Pycharm Plugin installed.

Comment: I don't quite understand - usually, the minimum python version that you define in the poetry settings depends on the kind of features you use in your own code, i.e. on first party code and not on third. I wouldn't be surprised if no tool as you imagine it exists because noone (or too few) handle dependency analysis in the way you do it.

Comment: If you simply want to collect requirements given imports, [`pipreqs`](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs) seems to be the most popular one. It's not a trivial problem though, because an import statement and the name of the distribution on PyPI don't need to share the same name, for example `pip install beautifulsoup4` -> `import bs4`

Comment: @Arne Does `pipreqs` use the version of the package currently installed, or does it make any attempt to see if earlier versions would also work?

Comment: I think it just pins to the most recent version it can find (unless you pass `--no-pin`). python packages don't provide a static public API definition, so it's impossible for a tool to find out stuff like `feature A was added in version x.y.z`. ... by now I've got to ask, why are you so fixated on using a minimum version? From a practical point of view, taking the current version and caret-pinning it to the minor Just Works© for everyone, e.g. `sqlalchemy = "^1.3"`. Is it best practice in a different language?

Comment: @Arne I think that if v1.2 of a dependency would be sufficient, it is incorrect to require the user to install v1.9 and refuse to work with v1.3. I know that some developers like to say "well it's the user's fault for not having the latest version, screw him" but I disagree with that approach.

Comment: I think the discussion here is going a bit too in depth, as there is a disagreement at the conceptual level. Maybe someone else will show up who can help you or point you to a tool. But my personal conclusion is that 1) what you want to achieve is very hard, borderline impossible to do for a tool, and 2) similarly difficult for a maintainer, as you yourself have pointed out. You can only really test the API of 3rd parties whose version you actually have installed, which is why there is the implicit, if unfair, assumption of users having to have the latest version of everything.